# Need this if/else Statement to function with a click action from a button

Tags: javascript, html

Admittedly I'm really new to javascript and I assume what I am trying to do is simple but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to make this function work with the click of a button instead of a page load/reload.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var ic = 9; // Number of alternative images
    var xoxo = new Array(ic); // Array to hold filenames

    xoxo[0] = "images/StaminUp.png"
    xoxo[1] = "images/DoubleTap.png"
    xoxo[2] = "images/QucikRevive.png"
    xoxo[3] = "images/ElectricCherry.png"
    xoxo[4] = "images/Juggernog.png"
    xoxo[5] = "images/SpeedCola.png"
    xoxo[6] = "images/MuleKick.png"
    xoxo[7] = "images/WidowsWine.png"
    xoxo[8] = "images/DeadShot.png"

    function pickRandom() {
        if (Math.random)
            return [Math.floor(Math.random() * xoxo.length)];
        else {
            var now = new Date();
            return (now.getTime() / 1000) % xoxo.length;
        }
    }
    // Write out an IMG tag, using a randomly-chosen image name.
    var choice = pickRandom(ic);
    // -->
    
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p id="perk"></p>
<script>document.getElementById("perk").innerHTML = ('<img src= "'+xoxo[choice]+'">')</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the if statement? Are you just checking Math.random exists?

Comment: Obviously he do ... And even if not, it's not important for his question.

Answer (score 0):

So you just create a button with an id like this:

```
<button id="changeImage">Change Image</button>
```

Now you add an event listener to it which will be triggered if someone clicks on that button. The event listener will invoke a function, so I suggest to swap the image change to an own function.

```
    function changeImage() {
       document.getElementById("perk").innerHTML = ('<img src= "'+xoxo[pickRandom(ic)]+'">');
    }
```

This function you call in the beginning once:

```
changeImage();
```

And this function you will pass as parameter to the event listener:

```
document.getElementById("changeImage").addEventListener('click', changeImage);
```

Check out this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u0jw8u11/

Comment: Thank You! I managed to get it working, cant believe it took so long but thank you for explaining it for me.

Comment: Hi @nateschwarz. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark on the left. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.